# Json Parsing issue in Play 2.3

Tags: java, json, jackson, playframework-2.3

For some JSON requests my play application logs the following error.

```
2014-10-14 03:58:59 +0000 - [DEBUG] - from play in play-internal-execution-context-32582 
Invalid Json
java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-32 character 0x7b226174(above 10ffff)  at         char #362, byte #1451)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.UTF32Reader.reportInvalid(UTF32Reader.java:155) ~[com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.UTF32Reader.read(UTF32Reader.java:109) ~[com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.loadMore(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:131) ~[com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1688) ~[com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:562) ~[com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
```

What can cause this? Why it says UTF32, I assumed it is working with UTF-8.

Comment: I had seen a similar error in a different app and it was related to other encodings being parsed as UTF8. If that happens when you receive data from a browser check that the page encoding is right.